# Expanding a JavaScript menu with WebDriver

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click a button on a webpage with WebDriver which uses JavaScript to expand a menu revealing other links:

```
<div id="menu">
<div id="security_bt" class="advanced_white_close_button" onclick="open_or_close_sub('security');                
security_open++;"><b> <span languageCode = "13">Security</span></b></div>
<div id="advanced_bt" class="advanced_white_close_button" onclick="open_or_close_sub('advanced');     
advanced_open++;"><b><span languageCode = "3011">Advanced Setup</span></b></div>
...etc
```

I have tried using methods suggested on this site including Xpath and CSS

```
Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='advanced_bt']/b/span")).Click();
or
Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#advanced_bt > b > span")).Click();
```

and also tried with IJavaScriptExecutor:

```
            var executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver;
        executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Neither have worked. The test does not fail to locate the elements, so I'm out of ideas why the can't be clicked. If anyone can shed any light that would be appreciated. Cheers.

Oh and this is the onclick= code:

```
function open_or_close_sub(name)
{

var button_name= name+"_bt";
var sub_name= name+"_sub";
var open_flag= top.document.getElementById(sub_name).style.display;

close_all_sub(sub_name);/* fold all menus first, except the menu which user click*/

var button_div = top.document.getElementById(button_name);
var content_length = button_div.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML.length;
if( open_flag == "none")
{
    settingClass(button_div, content_length, "advanced_white_open_button", top.region_class.white_triple, top.region_class.white_double);
    top.document.getElementById(sub_name).style.display="";
}
else
{
    settingClass(button_div, content_length, "advanced_white_close_button", top.region_class.white_triple, top.region_class.white_double);
    top.document.getElementById(sub_name).style.display="none";
}
change_menu_height();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@id='advanced_bt']//span[.='Advanced Setup']")).Click();
```

It will click on the **'span element', under div tag with id 'advanced_vt', and having exact innerHTML/text as 'Advanced Setup'**

Or try the below code using **Actions class**:

```
Actions action  = new Actions(Browser.Driver);
action.MoveToElement(Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@id='advanced_bt']//span[.='Advanced Setup']"))).Click().Perform();
```

---

### EDIT 07.12.14

In case, that still doesn't work, then using **IJavascriptExecutor**, set the **attribute of the submenu to be visible**, and then proceed on taking further actions on the submenu. From the image in the comments, the below code will reveal the submenu under 'Advanced Setup':

```
 IWebElement element = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@id='advanced_sub']"));
 var executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver;
 executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].style.display='block';", element);
```

Comment: Have tried but it doesn't work, including finding the menu element first then selecting advanced_bt from those elements.

Comment: Do you have to click on some menu first, and then the div having id  **advanced_bt** is visible after that ?

Comment: advanced_bt is one of a visible list of buttons within <div id="menu">. When clicked each expand their own list of submenu links.

Comment: Is the menu a part of some frame ?

Comment: There is a topframe and formframe but WebDriver is finding the elements in the formframe (have tried switching to this also). Here is a pic of the page with the Advanced Setup menu expanded if that helps. Cheers. http://rickkomer.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/netgear_genie3.jpg

Comment: Do one thing. Open the page in Firefox. And, assuming you do have the **Firebug** with **Firepath** on it, inspect the element **"Advanced Setup"** menu, and check if an iframe gets displayed on top-left of the firebug like this image:[http://i.imgur.com/H3Y08SF.png](http://i.imgur.com/H3Y08SF.png). Do the same thing with the menu items under it. If the iframe(s) are displayed for each of them, please let me know here, what are those ? If not then, then the task is even easy.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about Firepath. There are mentions of iframe in the firepath dropdown but 'Top Window' is selected (see screenshot). The other menu items are in a similar format: http://i.imgur.com/BKiVjtT.png

Comment: @3lysium: I have modified my code above.. See if it works. If it doesn't, please tell me, if [you've given sufficient timeout](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits). Also, if when manually clicked on, does it require a single or double click to get the dropdown list under **Advanced Setup**

Comment: `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait((IWebDriver)Browser.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            var imgs = wait.Until(d =>
            {
             return Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='advanced_bt']//span[.='Advanced Setup']"));
            });
            Console.WriteLine(imgs.Text); //output: Advanced Setup

            
Actions action = new Actions((IWebDriver)Browser.Driver);
            var btn = action.MoveToElement(imgs);
            btn.Click().Perform();`

Tried your code and this, the element is found, but the menu does not expand

Comment: The menu takes a single click...this is so bizarre.

Comment: Even I am stumped by this. :) Anyways try double clicking using the code `action.MoveToElement(Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@id='advanced_bt']//span[.='Advanced Setup']"))).DoubleClick().Perform();`. And, if all else fails, I have added an alternative using **IJavascriptExecutor** for revealing the submenu items. Hope that helps. Please let me know how it goes..

Comment: IJavaScriptExecutor worked, amazing! Thanks so much.

Comment: @3lysium: Glad it worked out.. FYI, the above code for **IJavascriptExecutor** is just changing the display attribute of the submenu to block.. That means, the click on the main menu still doesn't work.. I hope you get that.. Cheers..:)